# Could not convert video to audio using ffmpeg or moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I want to convert a mp4 video file to mp3/wav audio using python ffmpeg or moviepy.
when I run this command

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -ar 44100 -vn audio.wav
```

It returns

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Here is the full Log

```
ffmpeg version N-55702-g920046a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 21 2013 18:10:00 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 42.100 / 52. 42.100
  libavcodec     55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavformat    55. 14.101 / 55. 14.101
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 82.100 /  3. 82.100
  libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-03-12 14:13:58
  Duration: 00:07:28.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1199 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1197 kb/s, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-12 14:13:58
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Output #0, wav, to 'audio.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I searched the internet for this but could not find a solution

Please tell if there is a way to do this with ffmpeg or another way

I also tried to use moviepy but it was not successful.

Here is moviepy log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\file\script.py", line 3, in <module>
    clip.audio.write_audiofile(r'audio.mp3')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_audiofile'
```

this is my code for moviepy

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip('vid.mp4')
clip.audio.write_audiofile(r'audio.mp3')
```

Comment: Your video vile appears to be missing audio

Comment: yes my audio file has audio

Comment: Well ffmpeg doesn't think so :) Are you able to share the video file publicly?

Answer (score 0):

It must mean that the `vid.mp4` files cannot be found by the program. Make sure that the `vid.py` file is in the same directory as the `ffmpeg.exe` *(or make sure you cd into the same directory as the `vid.mp4` file in your command prompt)* and your python file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying out moviepy, and can hopefully help you. Are you able to try this:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip('vid.mp4')
audio = clip.audio
audio.write_audiofile('audio.mp3')
```